# IBM x3650 M3 installation 10.04LTS

Tags: installation, server, drivers

Hi Just about to purchase two IBM servers x3650 and need to run 10.04LTS as it is the only version that will support a particular application. The server has the following Spec:

- IBM System x3650 M3 - 6Core, 48GB, 2x460W PSU, Multi Burner DVD
- 7945KNG x3650 M3, Xeon 6C E5645 80W 2.40GHz/1333MHz/12MB,1x4GB, O/Bay
  HS 2.5in SAS/SATA, SR
- M5014, Multi-Burner 460W p/s, Rack
- Intel Xeon 6C Processor Model E5645 80w 2.40GHz/1333MHz/12MB
- 48GB
- 5TB hdd in a Raid 5 config
- ServeRAID M5015 SAS/SATA Controller
- IBM Virtual Media Key

Does anyone know if this version of Ubuntu will support this as i can't find anything on the web

Thanks in Advance
darren

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 TLS onto this server without too many hickups, things to watch out for are gfx drivers and of course setting the raid drivers prior to install, If you know what these drivers are it is fairly straight forward.

Comment: You may want to expand on your answer. *things to watch out for are gfx drivers*- Like?, *and of course setting the raid drivers prior to install*- How?.